# Azure Redis delete cache command not executing

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to delete the cache I created to reset the data, but when I run the following command

```
az redis delete --name listings --resource-group appsvc_linux_centralus
```

it says

```
Are you sure you want to perform this operation? (y/n): y
```

When I enter y, it returns nothing

[image]

I know it didn't work because when I refresh the page to hit this code

```
  client.get("listings", (err, reply) => {

console.log(reply);

  });
return;
```

It outputs all 30 listings from the cache. So the name is definitely correct and the resource group is grabbed from portal inside Redis service.

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't delete. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you trying to delete the data or the redis cache account itself?

Comment: I was trying to clear all the data inside the listings cache so that I can start with fresh data. Not the account itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using the command incorrectly. Based on the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/redis?view=azure-cli-latest#az-redis-delete), this command actually deletes the redis cache account and not the data itself.

> ## az redis delete
>
> Deletes a Redis cache.

If you wish to clear the data, I believe you will need to use one of the Redis Cache SDKs and perform purge data operation using [`FLUSHALL`](https://redis.io/commands/flushall) command.